# iOS 14 delayed?

Tags: software-update, ios

I have been waiting for almost 2 hours for the iOS 14 update on my iPhone 11 Pro Max. I noticed that it hasn't been released yet, but some people say that they have the official release (not GM).

If that is true, I'm wondering if there are any releases to specific regions, but not all at once.

[image: iOS_13_7]

Comment: I notice that I have 1 downvote. Any ideas on how I can improve my question?

Comment: This question should be deleted!

Comment: As of now, probably.

Comment: This is really a yes/no question and doesn’t really help people at all now or in a week IMO. I didn’t -1 it, but I understand why people would vote it down

Comment: I was notified on my **iPhone** at ~11:00 AM on the east coast of the US that **iOS 14** was ready to be installed on my device.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has no value to anyone who comes to read the site now or in the future.

Comment: @user3439894 I can't delete the question

Comment: Macintosh Fan, If you want to delete it,  you could just put a message asking one of the moderators to delete the question at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat and don't forget to post the URL of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the current date and time (Sept 16, 7:07pm GMT), Apple has not released the software to the public.

Some people have the beta installed so that's why they have it already.

Update 8:37pm GMT: It looks like the updates are rolling out now around the world.